# Chrome not scrolling with touchpad

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, touchpad, scrolling, windows-10-v1607

not sure where I should be posting this but:

In the last few weeks, chrome has developed an intermittant problem of not allowing me to scroll using my laptop's touchpad. The mouse works in chrome during this, the touchpad scrolls as it should in every other program. If I kill all chrome processes and restart it, it will continue to work fine for a while and then inexplicably stop some time later.

Having played with the touch/scroll settings in `chrome://flags`, I know it isn't affected by those options.

My system:

Windows 10 (anniversary version 1607)

Surface Book

Any ideas? Any one else experiencing this?

Thanks

Comment: https://www.cnet.com/how-to/fixing-windows-10-touchpad-problems/  have you tried these suggestions?

Comment: Yes I have, It's specifically a chrome problem

Comment: tried something like this? https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/smoothscroll/nbokbjkabcmbfdlbddjidfmibcpneigj

Comment: I used to have that. I've already tried with that installed. No change

Comment: Does an external (usb) mouse work to scroll?

Comment: Yes  it's just the touch pad specifically on chrome windows

Comment: To weed out and make sure it isn't an add on or something, could you try browsing as a guest? Click the account in the top right of Chrome, select "switch person" then select "browse as guest" in bottom left. It should start a new browser window. See if that one has the same issue.

Comment: The annoying thing is that it is very intermittent. So I'll try browsing with both   mine and a guest account for a while and get back to you

Comment: No problem. Is it on specific sites or does it seem to stop working halfway through a page?

Comment: Any site. Including chrome pages like flags and settings

Comment: This sounds like hardware interaction with chrome, try this: http://www.windowscentral.com/how-enable-smooth-scrolling-google-chrome-surface

Comment: Yeah, I thought that, but no. The problem persists regardless of scroll settings in flags (including smooth scroll)

Comment: OK, it happened again, in both guest and account windows simultaneously whilst I was browsing normally and switching tabs

Comment: Ok, this post on the Google Product Forum for Chrome suggests installing a theme (any theme) and for some reason that fixes it: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/qtNYPbUIcoI

Edit: link the themes page: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/themes

Comment: OK, sounds like it might just refresh but I'll try it

Comment: My last idea is make sure all drivers and firmware are up to date:https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49497

Comment: I do not know about the structure of the Surface Book you.
But I know I should check to see if the driver is installed touchpad?
And have not been checked out some features disabled the touchpad.
You must check the Advanced Settings keyboard Search.

Comment: Again. The touchpad works everywhere else except in chrome windows

Comment: Lucidnonsense, did the other suggestions change anything?

Comment: I'm trying out the theme idea. So far it looks promising but I didn't want to mark it as resolved quite yet: I haven't had a chance to use my laptop. I will get back to you

Comment: OK, no that didn't work. None of these ideas have worked

Comment: Do you have Kaspersky antivirus installed?  There is anecdotal evidence that removing KAV will resolve the issue. Have you tried safe mode (with networking)? Have you tried the latest chrome beta release, https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/canary.html.

Comment: I usually don't try to throw the kitchen sink at issues, but you appear stuck pretty solidly, so consider running the chrome cleanup utility as well. Also a full chrome uninstall/ reinstall. https://www.google.com/chrome/cleanup-tool/

Comment: I've done the uninstall/resinstall to no effect. However, I've tried removing kaspersky and the issue has not reappeared so far (hence my delay in replying). So if @Argonauts posts an answer I can give credit I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moved from comments-

Do you have Kaspersky antivirus installed? There is anecdotal evidence that removing KAV will resolve the issue.

Comment: This resolved this issue (and several others). I'm now in contact with Kaspersky

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, try clicking the settings (`⋮`) button in the top-right of Chrome, navigating to the nested bookmarks menu, and scrolling that listing with your mouse wheel.

That fixes touchpad scrolling / zooming within the rest of the browser for me.